# Komma bei zwei Relativsätzen, die sich dasselbe Hilfsverb teilen

Tags: comma, relative-clause

Gehört hier zwischen das vorletzte und das letze Wort ein Komma?

> Hochdeutsch ist eine Sprache, die standardisiert, also in Regelwerken abgebildet<sub>**(**</sub>,<sub>)</sub> ist.

Das Hilfsverb *»ist«* am Ende des Satzes gehört sowohl zu *»standardisiert«*, als auch zu *»abgebildet«*, denn der obige Satz ist eine Verschmelzung dieser beiden Sätze:

> 1. Hochdeutsch ist eine Sprache, die standardisiert ist.
> 2. Hochdeutsch ist eine Sprache, die in Regelwerken abgebildet ist.

Interpretiert man dieses *»ist«* am Ende des Satzes so, dass es zu *»standardisiert«* gehört, dann kann man es auch vorziehen, und direkt hinter *»standardisiert«* stellen:

> Hochdeutsch ist eine Sprache, die standardisiert **ist,** die also in Regelwerken abgebildet ist.

Dadurch wird es aber (zumindest nach meinem Sprachgefühl) notwendig, vor *»also«* das Relativpronomen *»die«* einzufügen, und dem Partizip *»abgebildet«* sein eigenes *»ist«* zu geben, weil es sonst ohne Hilfsverb dastünde. Dass hier kein Komma nach *»abgebildet«* stehen darf, liegt auf der Hand, denn das letzte Wort des Satzes gehört zu keinem anderem Wort als *»abgebildet«*, daher wäre an dieser Stelle ein Komma definitiv falsch.

Weitaus interessanter ist aber diese Variante:

> Hochdeutsch ist eine Sprache, die standardisiert, die also in Regelwerken abgebildet<sub>**(**</sub>,<sub>)</sub> ist.

Hier hat jeder der beiden Relativsätze sein eigenes Relativpronomen, aber sie teilen sich dasselbe Hilfsverb. Gehört hier ein Komma hin oder nicht?

Comment: Ich glaube, dein Sprachgefühl führt dich in die Irre - Ich glaube nicht, dass ein zweites Relativpronomen nach dem Komma absolut notwendig ist. Was du gebaut hast, ist ein zweiter Relativsatz. Es geht aber auch über eine Parenthese, die zum Relativsatz gehört. Je nachdem steht ein Relativpronomen oder nicht.

Comment: Regeln hin oder her, wenn wir beim Sprechen keine Pause machen, ist ein Komma so gut wie immer fehl am Platz.

Comment: @Takkat Die *meisten* fraglichen Kommata sind falsch oder freiwillig - Daher "im Zweifel lieber nicht"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deine Deutung des ursprünglichen Satzes als Hauptsatz mit zwei Relativsätzen ist *eine* von mehreren Möglichkeiten und du hast auch die Kommata jeweils nach dieser Deutung gesetzt. Zumindestens in einigen deiner Beispiele kann der zweite Relativsatz aber auch als Parenthese (was man einfach dadurch überprüfen kann, dass man den Einschub in Klammern setzt und es weiterhin "richtig" aussieht) oder auch als Zusatz oder Nachtrag gedeutet werden.

> Hochdeutsch ist eine Sprache, die standardisiert ist (also in Regelwerken abgebildet ist).

Wie man sieht, ist kein zweites Relativproniomen notwendig.

Zu deiner Frage am Schluß:

> Hochdeutsch ist eine Sprache, die standardisiert, die also in Regelwerken abgebildet<sub>**(**</sub>,<sub>)</sub> ist.

Ich denke, deinen Beispielsatz muß man nicht nach den Regeln für Nebensätze (die erklären nur das erste Komma), sondern nach den Rechtschreibregeln für *Zusätze und Nachträge (§77)* bewerten.

Die Hauptregel heißt:

> Zusätze  oder  Nachträge  grenzt  man  mit  Komma  ab;  sind  sie  eingeschoben, so schließt man sie mit paarigem Komma ein.

Ein Stück weiter unten steht in den Erläuterungen zu Punkt (4), speziell zu *also*, Folgendes:

> Wird – im Unterschied zu den letztgenannten Beispielen – die Erläuterung in die substantivische oder verbale Fügung einbezogen, so grenzt 
>   man sie mit einfachem Komma ab...

Das bedeutet für mich: Nachdem du das zweite "ist" weglässt, ist "in die verbale Fügung einbezogen" erfüllt, damit kein zweites Komma.